# Python - Finding multiple values in python array list in order

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to find multiple values in python array list in order and merge returned data.

`arr = [('var1','val1'),('var2','val2'),('var3','val3'),('var4','val4'),('var1','val5'),('var3','val6'),('var5','val7'),('var1','val8'),('var3','val9'),('var6','val10')]`

`find1 = 'var1'`
this shall return val1

`find2 = 'var1 var3'`
this shall return  val5, val6

`find2 = 'var1 var3 var6'`
this shall return  val8, val9, val10

I couldnt find any example about finding multiple values in order, so needed to open this question

thanks

Comment: Why not `find2 = 'var1 var3'` return : `val1, val3`?

Comment: because var3 doesnt comes after var1

Comment: So we can **NOT** ask `find2 = 'var1 var4'`?!

Comment: we can but it shall not find anything

Answer (score 2):

One solution:

```
arr = [('var1', 'val1'), ('var2', 'val2'),
       ('var3', 'val3'), ('var4', 'val4'),
       ('var1', 'val5'), ('var3', 'val6'),
       ('var5', 'val7'), ('var1', 'val8'),
       ('var3', 'val9'), ('var6', 'val10')]

finds = ['var1', 'var1 var3', 'var1 var3 var6']

keys, values = zip(*arr)
for find in finds:
    b = tuple(find.split())

    # find the first index of the matching sequence
    index = next(i for i in range(len(arr)) if keys[i:i + len(b)] == b)

    # join the result from the matching index to the required length
    res = " ".join(values[index:index + len(b)])
    print(res)
```

**Output**

```
val1
val5 val6
val8 val9 val10
```

As an alternative use [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher):

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

arr = [('var1', 'val1'), ('var2', 'val2'),
       ('var3', 'val3'), ('var4', 'val4'),
       ('var1', 'val5'), ('var3', 'val6'),
       ('var5', 'val7'), ('var1', 'val8'),
       ('var3', 'val9'), ('var6', 'val10')]

finds = ['var1', 'var1 var3', 'var1 var3 var6']

keys, values = zip(*arr)
for find in finds:
    b = find.split()
    s = SequenceMatcher()
    s.set_seqs(keys, b)
    match = s.find_longest_match()
    res = " ".join(values[match.a:match.a+match.size])
    print(res)
```

**Output**

```
val1
val5 val6
val8 val9 val10
```

Comment: this works great  friend
if this array change like that how can i let it work


`arr = [('var1', 'val1', 'val1-2', 'val1-3'), ('var2', 'val2', 'val2-2', 'val2-3'),
       ('var3', 'val3', 'val3-2', 'val3-3'), ('var4', 'val4', 'val4-2', 'val4-3'),
       ('var1', 'val5', 'val5-2', 'val5-3'), ('var3', 'val6', 'val6-2', 'val6-3'),
       ('var5', 'val7', 'val7-2', 'val7-3'), ('var1', 'val8', 'val8-2', 'val8-3'),
       ('var3', 'val9', 'val9-2', 'val9-3'), ('var6', 'val10', 'val10-2', 'val10-3')]`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend transforming your list into the dictionary:

```
dct = {i[0]:i[1] for i in arr}
```

Then use this function to return multiplies values from your dictionary as your described in your question:

```
def findMultiple(dct, find):
    find = find.split(" ")
    results = [dct[key] for key in find]
    return " ".join(results)
```

Usage:

```
>>> findMultiple(dct, "var1")
'val8'
>>> findMultiple(dct, "var1 var3")
'val8 val9'
>>> findMultiple(dct, "var1 var3 var6")
'val8 val9 val10'
```